# Get CSS Flexbox layout to wrap around a content area

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to build an HTML/CSS Flexbox layout for my new project using code snippets from http://www.flexboxpatterns.com

My current demo of what I have so far is on CodePen here - http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/OWbXNB?editors=1000

Below is the link to each of the 5 Flexbox snippets I am trying to use.  It is basically

**Flexbox HTML/CSS Example Snippets from flexboxpatterns.com**

- Site Header Snippet = http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/site-header
- Left Sidebar Snippet = http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/side-bar
- Form Footer Snippet = http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/form-footer
- Centered Prompt - should be right of sidebar but instead shows below everything else = http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/centered-prompt
- Gallery Flexbox - also should be right of left sidebar but is shown below all content = http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/gallery

---

[image]

---

### HTML For Flexbox Layout

```
<!-- START HEADER -->
<div class="siteHeader">
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
  <div class="siteHeader__section">
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderLogo">
      <div class="fa fa-inbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton is-site-header-item-selected">Inbox</div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Sent</div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Trash</div>
  </div>
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
  <div class="siteHeader__section">
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Settings</div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Log out</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->




<!-- START LEFT SIDEBAR -->
<div class="sideBar">
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the top-->
  <div class="sideBar__section">
    <div class="sideBar__item is-side-bar-item-selected">Inbox</div>
    <div class="sideBar__item">Contacts</div>
    <div class="sideBar__item">Account</div>
  </div>
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the bottom-->
  <div class="sideBar__section">
    <div class="sideBar__item">Change theme</div>
    <div class="sideBar__item">Legal</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR -->




<!-- START BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->
<div class="formFooter">
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
  <div class="formFooter__section">
    <div class="formFooter__item formFooterFeedback">
      <div class="fa fa-spinner formFooterSpinner"></div>&nbsp;Saving...
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
  <div class="formFooter__section">
    <div class="formFooter__item button button--clear">Reset</div>
    <div class="formFooter__item button">Save</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->





<!-- START GALLERY -->
<!-- IT SHOULKD BE TO THE RIGHT OF THE LEFT SIDEBAR BUT IS CURRENTLY BELOW THE SIDEBAR AND FORM FOOTER BAR -->
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo photo1 photo--large">1</div>
  <div class="photo photo2 photo--large">2</div>
  <div class="photo photo3 photo--large">3</div>
  <div class="photo photo4 photo--large">4</div>
  <div class="photo photo5 photo--large">5</div>
  <div class="photo photo6 photo--large">6</div>
  <div class="photo photo7 photo--large">7</div>
  <div class="photo photo8 photo--large">8</div>
  <div class="photo photo9 photo--large">9</div>
  <div class="photo photo10 photo--large">10</div>
</div>
<!-- END GALLERY -->





<!-- START CENTERED PROMPT -->
<!-- THIS ALSO SHOULD BE RIGHT OF THE LEFT SIDEBAR IT IS JUST A RGHR CONTENT AREA BUT IS SHOWING BELOW  -->
<!-- THE SIDEBAR NOW UNTIL IT IS FIXED -->
<div class="centeredPrompt">
  <div class="centeredPrompt__item centeredPromptIcon">
    <div class="icon fa fa-smile-o"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="centeredPrompt__item centeredPromptLabel">Welcome to the app!</div>
  <div class="centeredPrompt__item centeredPromptDetails">Thanks for signing up. Let&rsquo;s take a look around.</div>
  <div class="centeredPrompt__item button">Begin tour</div>
</div>
<!-- END CENTERED PROMPT -->
```

---

### CSS For Above Flexbox HTML

```
.siteHeader {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Make the container put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either
   * end laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #56727C;
}

.siteHeader__section {
  /**
     * Lay out the children of this container with
     * flexbox.
     */
  display: flex;
  /**
     * Align the children in the center, along
     * the main axis. By default the children will
     * align along their top edges.
     */
  align-items: center;
}

.siteHeader__item {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.siteHeader__item + .siteHeader__item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.siteHeader__item.is-site-header-item-selected {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #415F69;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.siteHeaderLogo {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0;
  color: white;
}

.siteHeaderButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #D9E9EF;
}

.sideBar {
  /**
   * This container orders items according to flexbox
   * rules. By default, this would arrange its children
   * horizontally. However, the next property...
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * ...sets the main axis to be vertical instead of
   * horizontal, so now the children are laid out
   * vertically, from top to bottom.
   */
  flex-direction: column;
  /**
   * It will also put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either end
   * laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  background-color: #FCFDFD;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sideBar__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #16A2D7;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sideBar__item.is-side-bar-item-selected {
  background-color: #EEF3F5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.formFooter {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Make the container put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either
   * end laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /**
   * Align the children in the center, along
   * the main axis, which is horizontal in this case.
   */
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  padding: 10px;
}

.formFooter__section {
  /**
     * This container orders items horizontally.
     */
  display: flex;
  /**
     * It aligns them vertically in the center.
     */
  align-items: center;
}

.formFooter__item + .formFooter__item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.formFooterFeedback {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.formFooterSpinner {
  animation: formFooterSpinner 1s infinite steps(8, end);
}

@keyframes formFooterSpinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.button--clear {
  color: #16A2D7;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.centeredPrompt {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Rotate the main axis so that the children
   * are laid out vertically, the same as in the
   * above "Side bar" example.
   */
  flex-direction: column;
  /**
   * Instead of pushing the children apart, as in
   * previous examples, we will group them together
   * in the center of their container.
   */
  justify-content: center;
  /**
   * Align the children in the center, along
   * the main axis. Because the direction is
   * "column" this has a similar effect as setting
   * text-align: center.
   */
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.centeredPrompt__item + .centeredPrompt__item {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.centeredPromptIcon {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.centeredPromptLabel {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.centeredPromptDetails {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  color: #BCD2DA;
}

.gallery {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Allow the children to wrap to the next "row",
   * instead of trying to squeeze them all into
   * a single row.
   */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 478px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
}

.photo2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_2.jpg');
}

.photo3 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_3.jpg');
}

.photo4 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_4.jpg');
}

.photo5 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_5.jpg');
}

.photo6 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_1.jpg');
}

.photo7 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_2.jpg');
}

.photo8 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_3.jpg');
}

.photo9 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_4.jpg');
}

.photo10 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_5.jpg');
}
```

---

### Where I need Help

How can I get content to be to the right of the left sidebar and then a footer bar that is the width of the header?

Comment: having a really difficult time understanding what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Is this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YNNQje?editors=1100

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes that is basically what I am after.  From there the only thing different in the right content panel is some of my views will need a right sidebar to the right of the right content buyt most of my views would just fill that area thanks

Comment: @JasonDavis np. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood you right, here's my attempt with flexbox. For the most part, I moved the content next to sidebar and wrapped them both into a `container` with:

```
.container{display: flex; flex-direction: row;}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZZXOZ

Comment: That is what I am after!  Could you show an example with a right sidebar to the right of the right content panel as well?  Sometimes clicking an item in my right panel will open up related settings in a right sidebar to the right of the new center/right panel

Comment: Sure thing, it's really easy. You can just grab the left sidebar and insert it inside of the .container but after main: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QddgRW

Comment: @GCyrillus I think he was talking about adding a right-side panel as well as left, not instead of. I know the language is a little difficult but that's how I understood it.

Comment: i only pointed out at the possibillity to reverse the layout without modifying the HTML. i understood he wanted the sidebar standing on the right side :) not spliting it on both sides .

Comment: @SergChernata updated my CodePen http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/OWbXNB?editors=1000 looks good now as to what i needed check it out I have 3-4 examples.

Comment: I need to add a header DIV above the right content panel and a footer to the new right sidebar like this image shows = https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2017/chrome_2017-01-18_18-14-46.png ... if you care to help.  Everything I tried so far makes the header div show to the left of the content instead of above it.   Either way thanks for the help

Comment: I posted as a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731426/add-a-footer-div-and-header-div-to-my-current-css-flexbox-layout

Answer (score 1):

Move the `.sideBar`, `.gallery`, and `.centeredPrompt` sections into a new element on the page between the header and footer, and apply `display: flex;` to that new element. Then introduce another new element wrapping `.centeredPrompt` and `.gallery` and apply `flex-grow: 1;` so that it takes up the available space left over from `.sideBar`. Then position `.gallery` and `.centeredPrompt` as you see fit.

```css
.siteHeader {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Make the container put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either
   * end laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #56727C;
}

.siteHeader__section {
  /**
     * Lay out the children of this container with
     * flexbox.
     */
  display: flex;
  /**
     * Align the children in the center, along
     * the main axis. By default the children will
     * align along their top edges.
     */
  align-items: center;
}

.siteHeader__item {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.siteHeader__item + .siteHeader__item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.siteHeader__item.is-site-header-item-selected {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #415F69;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.siteHeaderLogo {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0;
  color: white;
}

.siteHeaderButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #D9E9EF;
}

.sideBar {
  /**
   * This container orders items according to flexbox
   * rules. By default, this would arrange its children
   * horizontally. However, the next property...
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * ...sets the main axis to be vertical instead of
   * horizontal, so now the children are laid out
   * vertically, from top to bottom.
   */
  flex-direction: column;
  /**
   * It will also put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either end
   * laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  background-color: #FCFDFD;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sideBar__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #16A2D7;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sideBar__item.is-side-bar-item-selected {
  background-color: #EEF3F5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.formFooter {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Make the container put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either
   * end laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /**
   * Align the children in the center, along
   * the main axis, which is horizontal in this case.
   */
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  padding: 10px;
}

.formFooter__section {
  /**
     * This container orders items horizontally.
     */
  display: flex;
  /**
     * It aligns them vertically in the center.
     */
  align-items: center;
}

.formFooter__item + .formFooter__item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.formFooterFeedback {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.formFooterSpinner {
  animation: formFooterSpinner 1s infinite steps(8, end);
}

@keyframes formFooterSpinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.button--clear {
  color: #16A2D7;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.centeredPrompt {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Rotate the main axis so that the children
   * are laid out vertically, the same as in the
   * above "Side bar" example.
   */
  flex-direction: column;
  /**
   * Instead of pushing the children apart, as in
   * previous examples, we will group them together
   * in the center of their container.
   */
  justify-content: center;
  /**
   * Align the children in the center, along
   * the main axis. Because the direction is
   * "column" this has a similar effect as setting
   * text-align: center.
   */
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.centeredPrompt__item + .centeredPrompt__item {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.centeredPromptIcon {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.centeredPromptLabel {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.centeredPromptDetails {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  color: #BCD2DA;
}

.gallery {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Allow the children to wrap to the next "row",
   * instead of trying to squeeze them all into
   * a single row.
   */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 478px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
}


.photo2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_2.jpg');
}

.photo3 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_3.jpg');
}

.photo4 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_4.jpg');
}

.photo5 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_5.jpg');
}

.photo6 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_1.jpg');
}

.photo7 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_2.jpg');
}

.photo8 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_3.jpg');
}

.photo9 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_4.jpg');
}

.photo10 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_5.jpg');
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- START HEADER -->
<div class="siteHeader">
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
  <div class="siteHeader__section">
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderLogo">
      <div class="fa fa-inbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton is-site-header-item-selected">Inbox</div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Sent</div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Trash</div>
  </div>
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
  <div class="siteHeader__section">
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Settings</div>
    <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Log out</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->


<!-- START LEFT SIDEBAR -->
<div class="flex">
  <div class="sideBar">
    <!-- This section gets pushed to the top-->
    <div class="sideBar__section">
      <div class="sideBar__item is-side-bar-item-selected">Inbox</div>
      <div class="sideBar__item">Contacts</div>
      <div class="sideBar__item">Account</div>
    </div>
    <!-- This section gets pushed to the bottom-->
    <div class="sideBar__section">
      <div class="sideBar__item">Change theme</div>
      <div class="sideBar__item">Legal</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR -->

  <div class="main">
    <!-- START GALLERY -->
    <!-- IT SHOULKD BE TO THE RIGHT OF THE LEFT SIDEBAR BUT IS CURRENTLY BELOW THE SIDEBAR AND FORM FOOTER BAR -->
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="photo photo1 photo--large">1</div>
      <div class="photo photo2 photo--large">2</div>
      <div class="photo photo3 photo--large">3</div>
      <div class="photo photo4 photo--large">4</div>
      <div class="photo photo5 photo--large">5</div>
      <div class="photo photo6 photo--large">6</div>
      <div class="photo photo7 photo--large">7</div>
      <div class="photo photo8 photo--large">8</div>
      <div class="photo photo9 photo--large">9</div>
      <div class="photo photo10 photo--large">10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- END GALLERY -->


    <!-- START CENTERED PROMPT -->
    <!-- THIS ALSO SHOULD BE RIGHT OF THE LEFT SIDEBAR IT IS JUST A RGHR CONTENT AREA BUT IS SHOWING BELOW  -->
    <!-- THE SIDEBAR NOW UNTIL IT IS FIXED -->
    <div class="centeredPrompt">
      <div class="centeredPrompt__item centeredPromptIcon">
        <div class="icon fa fa-smile-o"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="centeredPrompt__item centeredPromptLabel">Welcome to the app!</div>
      <div class="centeredPrompt__item centeredPromptDetails">Thanks for signing up. Let&rsquo;s take a look around.</div>
      <div class="centeredPrompt__item button">Begin tour</div>
    </div>
    <!-- END CENTERED PROMPT -->
  </div>
</div>


<!-- START BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->
<div class="formFooter">
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
  <div class="formFooter__section">
    <div class="formFooter__item formFooterFeedback">
      <div class="fa fa-spinner formFooterSpinner"></div>&nbsp;Saving...
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
  <div class="formFooter__section">
    <div class="formFooter__item button button--clear">Reset</div>
    <div class="formFooter__item button">Save</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->
```