# Add a Footer DIV and Header DIV to my current CSS Flexbox Layout

Tags: css, flexbox

Below is the CSS FLexbox layout I am working on.  A live example is here as well as on this CodePen which is constantly updated: http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/OWbXNB?editors=1100

I need to add 2 DIV's to the layout and need help getting them positioned where I need them.

- Add a header DIV above the right content panel
- Add a Form Footer DIV like the current wrapper Footer with save and reset buttons along with saving indicator at the bottom of the Right Sidebar
- Lastly I need to remove the current footer, so basdically the current footer just needs to be moved to the right sidebar.

So far I have tried multiple Flexbox CSS properties to try and get it into the desired positions with no luck so far.

This image shows what I need better...
[image]

### Demo

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  max-width: 1076px;
}
.button {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #4EBBE4;
  border: 1px solid #16A2D7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Raleway, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.siteHeader {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Make the container put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either
   * end laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #56727C;
}
.siteHeader__section {
  /**
     * Lay out the children of this container with
     * flexbox.
     */
  display: flex;
  /**
     * Align the children in the center, along
     * the main axis. By default the children will
     * align along their top edges.
     */
  align-items: center;
}
.siteHeader__item {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.siteHeader__item + .siteHeader__item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.siteHeader__item.is-site-header-item-selected {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #415F69;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.siteHeaderLogo {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0;
  color: white;
}
.siteHeaderButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #D9E9EF;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.sideBar {
  /**
   * This container orders items according to flexbox
   * rules. By default, this would arrange its children
   * horizontally. However, the next property...
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * ...sets the main axis to be vertical instead of
   * horizontal, so now the children are laid out
   * vertically, from top to bottom.
   */
  flex-direction: column;
  /**
   * It will also put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either end
   * laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #FCFDFD;
  padding: 10px;
}
.sideBar-left {
  border-right: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
}
.sideBar-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  width: 750px;
}
.sideBar__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #16A2D7;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.sideBar__item.is-side-bar-item-selected {
  background-color: #EEF3F5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.formFooter {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Make the container put as much space as possible
   * between its children, with the children at either
   * end laying flush against the container's edges.
   */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /**
   * Align the children in the center, along
   * the main axis, which is horizontal in this case.
   */
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #D7DBDD;
  padding: 10px;
}
.formFooter__section {
  /**
     * This container orders items horizontally.
     */
  display: flex;
  /**
     * It aligns them vertically in the center.
     */
  align-items: center;
}
.formFooter__item + .formFooter__item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.formFooterFeedback {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
}
.formFooterSpinner {
  animation: formFooterSpinner 1s infinite steps(8, end);
}
@keyframes formFooterSpinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.button--clear {
  color: #16A2D7;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.centeredPrompt {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Rotate the main axis so that the children
   * are laid out vertically, the same as in the
   * above "Side bar" example.
   */
  flex-direction: column;
  /**
   * Instead of pushing the children apart, as in
   * previous examples, we will group them together
   * in the center of their container.
   */
  justify-content: center;
  /**
   * Align the children in the center, along
   * the main axis. Because the direction is
   * "column" this has a similar effect as setting
   * text-align: center.
   */
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.centeredPrompt__item + .centeredPrompt__item {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.centeredPromptIcon {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 0;
}
.centeredPromptLabel {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
.centeredPromptDetails {
  color: #86969C;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon {
  color: #BCD2DA;
}
.gallery {
  /**
   * Lay out the children of this container with
   * flexbox, which is horizontal by default.
   */
  display: flex;
  /**
   * Allow the children to wrap to the next "row",
   * instead of trying to squeeze them all into
   * a single row.
   */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.photo {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 145px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #FFF;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 130px;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.photo.selected,
.photo:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
  border: 4px solid #F44336;
}
.photo1 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_2.jpg');
}
.photo2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_2.jpg');
}
.photo3 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_3.jpg');
}
.photo4 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_4.jpg');
}
.photo5 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_5.jpg');
}
.photo6 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_1.jpg');
}
.photo7 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_2.jpg');
}
.photo8 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_3.jpg');
}
.photo9 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_4.jpg');
}
.photo10 {
  background-image: url('http://www.flexboxpatterns.com/images/dog_5.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- START HEADER -->
  <div class="siteHeader">
    <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
    <div class="siteHeader__section">
      <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderLogo">
        <div class="fa fa-inbox"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton is-site-header-item-selected">Inbox</div>
      <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Sent</div>
      <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Trash</div>
    </div>
    <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
    <div class="siteHeader__section">
      <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Settings</div>
      <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Log out</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END HEADER -->


  <div class="container">

    <!-- START LEFT SIDEBAR -->
    <div class="sideBar sideBar-left">
      <!-- This section gets pushed to the top-->
      <div class="sideBar__section">
        <div class="sideBar__item is-side-bar-item-selected">Inbox</div>
        <div class="sideBar__item">Contacts</div>
        <div class="sideBar__item">Account</div>
      </div>
      <!-- This section gets pushed to the bottom-->
      <div class="sideBar__section">
        <div class="sideBar__item">Change theme</div>
        <div class="sideBar__item">Legal</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR -->


    <main>
      <!-- START GALLERY -->
      <!-- IT SHOULKD BE TO THE RIGHT OF THE LEFT SIDEBAR BUT IS CURRENTLY BELOW THE SIDEBAR AND FORM FOOTER BAR -->
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="photo photo1 photo--large">1</div>
        <div class="photo photo2 photo--large">2</div>
        <div class="photo photo3 photo--large">3</div>
        <div class="photo photo4 photo--large">4</div>
        <div class="photo photo5 photo--large">5</div>
        <div class="photo photo6 photo--large selected">6</div>
        <div class="photo photo7 photo--large">7</div>
        <div class="photo photo8 photo--large">8</div>
        <div class="photo photo9 photo--large">9</div>
        <div class="photo photo10 photo--large">10</div>
      </div>
      <!-- END GALLERY -->


    </main>
    <!-- END CENTERED PROMPT -->

    <!-- RIGHT-SIDEBAR-->
    <div class="sideBar sideBar-right">

      Form fields will be here loaded with Data from the selected image in the left panel
      <!-- This section gets pushed to the top-
      <div class="sideBar__section">
        <div class="sideBar__item is-side-bar-item-selected">Inbox</div>
        <div class="sideBar__item">Contacts</div>
        <div class="sideBar__item">Account</div>
      </div>
-->

    </div>
    <!-- END RIGHT-SIDEBAR-->
  </div>


  <!-- START BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->
  <div class="formFooter">
    <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
    <div class="formFooter__section">
      <div class="formFooter__item formFooterFeedback">
        <div class="fa fa-spinner formFooterSpinner"></div>&nbsp;Saving...
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
    <div class="formFooter__section">
      <div class="formFooter__item button button--clear">Reset</div>
      <div class="formFooter__item button">Save</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->

</div>
```

Comment: is the header and footer going to be a fixed height? or is content inside them variable height?

Comment: If you're aiming for fixed height items, i would suggest using `padding` and `position:absolute` to place your elements: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BppmNx?editors=1100

Comment: @haxxxton that's perfect thanbks if you post it i'll select it

Comment: you can also update a couple of the flex rules and add a header(in galery) and a footer(in sideBar-right) . http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dNNZVz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** This solution assumes that the toolbars arent going to be changing height on-the-fly.

The trick here is to apply `padding` to a `position:relative;` container, consistent with the sizing of a `position:absolute;` toolbar. Because it is likely you're going to be using the element's `formFooter` and `main` again, we will use utility classes to indicate that they have toolbars. These utility classes will contain the information about the `padding` and, in the case of the `formFooter`, extend their behaviour when a child of the utility class.

**CSS**

```
main.with-header{
  padding-top:50px;
  position:relative;
}
.gallery--header{
  height:50px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
}
.sideBar.sideBar-with-footer{
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
.sideBar.sideBar-with-footer .formFooter{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- START HEADER -->
    <div class="siteHeader">
        <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
        <div class="siteHeader__section">
            <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderLogo">
                <div class="fa fa-inbox"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton is-site-header-item-selected">Inbox</div>
            <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Sent</div>
            <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Trash</div>
        </div>
        <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
        <div class="siteHeader__section">
            <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Settings</div>
            <div class="siteHeader__item siteHeaderButton">Log out</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END HEADER -->

    <div class="container">

        <!-- START LEFT SIDEBAR -->
        <div class="sideBar sideBar-left">
            <!-- This section gets pushed to the top-->
            <div class="sideBar__section">
                <div class="sideBar__item is-side-bar-item-selected">Inbox</div>
                <div class="sideBar__item">Contacts</div>
                <div class="sideBar__item">Account</div>
            </div>
            <!-- This section gets pushed to the bottom-->
            <div class="sideBar__section">
                <div class="sideBar__item">Change theme</div>
                <div class="sideBar__item">Legal</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR -->

        <main class="with-header">
            <div class="gallery--header">
                <p>Gallery Header</p>
            </div>
            <!-- START GALLERY -->
            <!-- IT SHOULKD BE TO THE RIGHT OF THE LEFT SIDEBAR BUT IS CURRENTLY BELOW THE SIDEBAR AND FORM FOOTER BAR -->
            <div class="gallery">
                <div class="photo photo1 photo--large">1</div>
                <div class="photo photo2 photo--large">2</div>
                <div class="photo photo3 photo--large">3</div>
                <div class="photo photo4 photo--large">4</div>
                <div class="photo photo5 photo--large">5</div>
                <div class="photo photo6 photo--large selected">6</div>
                <div class="photo photo7 photo--large">7</div>
                <div class="photo photo8 photo--large">8</div>
                <div class="photo photo9 photo--large">9</div>
                <div class="photo photo10 photo--large">10</div>
            </div>
            <!-- END GALLERY -->

        </main>
        <!-- END CENTERED PROMPT -->

        <!-- RIGHT-SIDEBAR-->
        <div class="sideBar sideBar-right sideBar-with-footer">
            <!-- START BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->
            <div class="formFooter">
                <!-- This section gets pushed to the left side-->
                <div class="formFooter__section">
                    <div class="formFooter__item formFooterFeedback">
                        <div class="fa fa-spinner formFooterSpinner"></div>&nbsp;Saving...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- This section gets pushed to the right side-->
                <div class="formFooter__section">
                    <div class="formFooter__item button button--clear">Reset</div>
                    <div class="formFooter__item button">Save</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END BOTTOM FORM FOOTER BAR -->

        </div>
        <!-- END RIGHT-SIDEBAR-->
    </div>

</div>
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BppmNx?editors=1100)**

Comment: Great thanks and yes the height will be fixed size as they will hold icon buttons and maybe some text links like a breadcrumb trail